# Trying to run BluetoothChat on android 2.1

Tags: api, reflection, bluetooth, android-2.0-eclair

I'm trying to run the example SDK package BluetoothChat on a 2.1 (eclair) phone, but it crashes with

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord

Is there an easy way to get this to work?  Something such as simply bundle the newer version of android.bluetooth with my program?  I can run it fine on 4.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!  I used SDK manager to install the 2.1 example package, as well as the 2.1 SDK, made a new project with that, and it worked fine.